I can't receive emails from the Godaddy website contact form
When I send an e-mail, it says "Message sent successfully", but there is no e-mail in our e-mail box. Godaddy customer representative said that he made the spf setting. What should I do?
note: I tried the port number as 465 and 587 + the secure sending method of these ports.
My contact page code is:
<div id="iletisim">
   <div class="contact-container">
        <h3>İletişim Formu</h3>
        <form action="iletisim.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="isim" placeholder="Adınız" required>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" placeholder="E-posta" required>`your text`
            <textarea class="form-control" name="mesaj" placeholder="Mesajınız" rows="5" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Gönder">
        </form>
        <?php
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            require 'vendor/autoload.php';

            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            try {
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->Host = 'localhost';
                $mail->Port = 25;   
                $mail->SMTPSecure = false; 
                $mail->SMTPAuth = false; 
                $mail->Username = 'info@example.com';
                
                // Gönderici ve alıcı bilgileri
                $senderEmail = filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); // Formdan gelen mail
                $senderName = htmlspecialchars($_POST['isim']); // Güvenlik için isim temizleme

                if ($senderEmail) {
                    $mail->setFrom($senderEmail, $senderName); // Kullanıcı e-postası gönderici olarak ayarlanır
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('Geçersiz e-posta adresi.');
                }

                $mail->addAddress('info@example.com', 'xyz Yetkilisi');

                // Mesaj içeriği
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = 'Yeni Bir Mesaj';
                $mail->Body = 'Ad: ' . $senderName . '<br>' .
                              'E-posta: ' . $senderEmail . '<br>' .
                              'Mesaj: ' . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mesaj'])); // Mesaj güvenli şekilde

                $mail->send();
                echo '<p>Mesaj başarıyla gönderildi!</p>';
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo '<p>Mesaj gönderilemedi. Hata: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '</p>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>


Don't do this:
$mail->setFrom($senderEmail, $senderName);

This is forgery, and almost guarantees that your message will not be delivered. Instead, send from your own address, and add the submitter's address as a reply-to:
$mail->setFrom('contactform@example.com', 'Contact form');
$mail->addReplyTo($senderEmail, $senderName);

It's a good idea to base your code on the contact form example provided with PHPMailer as it avoids this problem, amongst others.
Also note that PHPMailer automatically validates email addresses everywhere they are used, so you don't need to do that yourself.
Also try setting $mail->SMTPDebug = 2 so that you can watch the delivery to the local mail server and check that there is nothing interesting coming back from the server.

I added the codes you sent, it returned 250 and 221. I still can't understand my problem.

There's nothing we can do without more info about what's happening ; edit your question and add debug output.

I spoke with the Godaddy customer representative. Our problem is actually that there is an email routing in the email section, the default here is local. In corporate company emails, this should be something like remote exchanger (the customer representative said) İt's ok. :)
